# raphael node selection

Tags: jquery, class, selection, raphael

I have lots of rects automatically created on a Raphael canvas, for simplicity this code only uses two:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var square = paper.rect(0 + 100*i, 0, 70, 70);
    square.node.setAttribute('id', '_' + i);
    square.node.setAttribute('class', 'foo');
}
```

which creates this chunk below (as seen with view selection source in Firefox):

```
<svg height="560" width="560" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><desc>Created with Raphael</desc><defs></defs><rect class="foo" id="_0" stroke="#000" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="70" width="70" y="0" x="0"></rect><rect class="foo" id="_1" stroke="#000" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="70" width="70" y="0" x="100"></rect></path></svg>
```

The css class indicates the color to fill. I would like to change the class of the each rect, individually, using a click function. I would need something like:

```
function change_class() {
    //something here
}
```

From everything I've read, this is done using `.node` , but here I don't have a separate variable for each `rect`, given that `square` was overwritten on each iteration of the `for()` loop.

One way to do this would be to push all rects to an array, like this:

```
squares = [];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var square = paper.rect(0 + 100*i, 0, 70, 70);
    square.node.idx = i;
    square.node.setAttribute('class', 'foo');
    squares.push(square);
}
```

I could then change the class directly via:

```
squares[0].node.setAttribute('class', 'other');
```

BUT... I still don't know how to do it via the general function `change_class()`... I need something like:

```
$('rect').click(function() {
    change_class(); // the click function should pass "$(this)" to change_class ?
});
```

What would be the right jQuery + Raphael method to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to click the box itself to change its color, you don't need jQuery, you can use Raphael's built-in event method, and refer to the rectangle as `this`, like so:

```
     rect.click( function () {
        this.node.setAttribute('class', 'newClass');
     });
```